# SQL Sum of certain rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL. I'm creating a database for an election, and I have 2 tables, the Party table and the Candidate table.

I'm creating a query that returns the ridingName, partyName, firstName, lastName, # of votes for the candidate, and the total # of votes cast in the riding, for the candidate with the most number of votes per riding. However, I'm having trouble with the part that returns the total number of votes cast per riding.

```
Party = {partyName, partyWebsite}
Candidate = {partyName, ridingName, firstName, lastName, votes} 
(votes here being the number of votes cast for that particular candidate)
```

Here is what I have so far..

```
SELECT C.ridingName, P.partyName, C.FirstName, C.LastName, C.votes, sum(C.votes) AS totalVotes --I tried to use sum to find total votes, but didn't quite work...
FROM Candidate C, Party P
WHERE C.votes = --this is to find the top candidate per riding
    (SELECT MAX(C1.votes)
    FROM Candidate C1
    WHERE C.ridingName = C1.ridingName) AND
    P.partyName = C.partyName   
GROUP BY C.ridingName, C.FirstName, C.LastName,P.partyName, C.votes
ORDER BY C.ridingName
```

Sample input + output:

[image]

Comment: My apologies, I added a sample input and output data at the bottom.

Comment: Remove `C.votes` from the `select` and `order by`. You only want `sum(C.votes)` in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query which attempts to generate your desired output based on the sample input from the `Candidate` table.

```
SELECT t1.ridingName, t1.partyName, t1.firstName, t1.lastName, t2.votes, t2.totalVotes
FROM Candidate t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT c.ridingName, MAX(votes) AS votes, SUM(votes) AS totalVotes
    FROM Candidate c
    GROUP BY c.ridingName
) t2
ON t1.ridingName = t2.ridingName AND t1.votes = t2.votes
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just like Tim mentioned, adding sample input and output data might help a lot. From what I understand you want a query like this:

```
with test as (
  select partyname, ridingname, firstname, lastname, 
         sum(votes) as totalvotes
  from candidate
  group by partyname, ridingname, firstname, lastname
)
select * from test
inner join (
  select ridingname, max(totalvotes) as maxvotes
  from test
  group by ridingname
) a on test.ridingname = a.ridingname and test.totalvotes = a.maxvotes
```

Example is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e95f3/6 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/077bd/1

EDIT:

Ah, just a little difference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a102d/8

```
with test as (
  select partyname, ridingname, firstname, lastname, 
         sum(votes) as totalvotes
  from candidate
  group by partyname, ridingname, firstname, lastname
)
select partyname, test.ridingname, firstname, lastname,
       totalvotes, allvotes 
from test
inner join (
  select ridingname, max(totalvotes) as maxvotes, sum(totalvotes) as allvotes
  from test
  group by ridingname
) a on test.ridingname = a.ridingname and test.totalvotes = a.maxvotes
```

Comment: Sorry, I added sample input and output data at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an edit and an example that gives you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Tim's suggestion was just a bit easier for me to read. Wish I had more reputation so I could upvote you...but thank you!

Comment: No problem at all. Tim's a much senior and experienced professional than I am and he comes up with great ways to solve problems.